# How make the code understand the last column

Tags: r

I would like to leave it "automatically" without having to specify `DR04` in this part of the code: `mutate(across(DR1:DR04, ~.x + get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV'))`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-08","2021-04-08"),
       Code = c("ABC","CDE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Friday","Friday","Thursday","Thursday"),
       DR1 = c(11,17,14,13),
       DR01 = c(14,11,14,13), DR02= c(14,12,16,17),DR03= c(19,15,14,13),
       DR04 = c(15,14,13,13)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR"))

x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
pk<-select(x, date2,Code, Week, DR1, ends_with("PV"))

med<-pk %>%
  group_by(Code, Week) %>%
  summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))

df1 %>%
  inner_join(med, by = c('Code', 'Week')) %>%
  mutate(across(DR1:DR04, ~.x + get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')), 
                .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Week, DR1_DR1_PV:last_col())

       date1      date2 Code     Week DR1_DR1_PV DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  ABC   Friday         11           11           11           11           11
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  CDE   Friday         17           17           17           17           17
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  ABC Thursday         14           14           14           14           14
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  CDE Thursday         13           13           13           13           13
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by "leave it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `matches`

```
df1 %>%
  inner_join(med, by = c('Code', 'Week')) %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("^DR\\d+$"), ~.x + 
        get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')), 
                .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Week, DR1_DR1_PV:last_col())
```

-output

```
      date1      date2 Code     Week DR1_DR1_PV DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  ABC   Friday         11           11           11           11           11
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  CDE   Friday         17           17           17           17           17
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  ABC Thursday         14           14           14           14           14
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  CDE Thursday         13           13           13           13           13
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(med, by = c('Code', 'Week')) %>%
  mutate(across(-(date1:Week) & !matches("_PV"), ~.x + get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')), 
                .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Week, DR1_DR1_PV:last_col())
```

which returns

```r
       date1      date2 Code     Week DR1_DR1_PV DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  ABC   Friday         11           11           11           11           11
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  CDE   Friday         17           17           17           17           17
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  ABC Thursday         14           14           14           14           14
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  CDE Thursday         13           13           13           13           13
```

We "deselect" the first columns (`date1:Week`) and every column containing `"_PV"`.